Prevent org-mode latex exporter from emitting \usepackage
I'm trying to generate a SIGPLAN document class from within org-mode.
So far, I have found that I need to add something like this to org-latex-classes:
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("sigplan"
               "\\documentclass[sigplan]{acmart}"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")))

However, when I generate the .tex file and then run xelatex on it, I get the following error:
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.261 ...ol{\Bbbk}           {\mathord}{AMSb}{"7C}

I've figured out that when I comment out \usepackage{amssymb} from the generated .tex file, the pdf is rendered successfully.
So my question is: how do I prevent the LaTeX exporter from adding that line? (Or whether there is some other workaround that would let me prevent this error?)

You can delete amssymb from the default list of packages. If you want to do it globally, you can add something like this in your init file:
(with-eval-after-load 'org
   (setq org-latex-default-packages-alist (delete '(""  "amssymb" t ("pdflatex")) org-latex-default-packages-alist)))

But you might want to use a File-local setting instead and add the following to any Org mode file that uses acmart (or whatever it is that conflicts with amssymb):

* COMMENT Local variables

Delete =amssymb= - it conflicts with =acmart=.

# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq org-latex-default-packages-alist (delete '(""  "amssymb" t ("pdflatex")) org-latex-default-packages-alist))
# End:

Some caveats: this section has to be at the very end of the Org mode file in order for Emacs to recognize it. In addition, make sure that the literal phrase Local Variables: (including the colon) occurs only in the above context, not somewhere else in your text where Emacs can get confused by it. See the documentation that I linked to above.

You can define your own LaTeX preamble with #+LATEX_HEADER: \input{header.tex}. See https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html.

You still need to inhibit the use of amssymb somehow if there is a conflict between it and what you want to use.
